# Custom sorting Queryset for columnview

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Moin Moin!

I have a model for appointments:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Appointment(models.Model):
    DateTime= models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    Name= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    Name= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.DatumZeit)
```

The table Appointment cointains an DateTime for every 10 minutes for each day.

For viewing it on the frontend in div's (bootstrap - row -col) I want the queryset to order that I have eg Appointment 1 to 12 in Column A, Appointment 13 to 24 in Column B, and so on.

In my views.py I tried it like this:

```
appointments = Appointments.objects.all()

        number = appointments.count()

        if (number % 4 == 0):
            block = number // 4
            rest = 0
        else:
            block = number // 3
            rest = number % 4


        x = 1
        appointments2 = ()

        for i in range(1, number):
            appointments2 += appointments[x + block]
            if x == 4:
                x = 1
            else:
                x += 1
```

I get an error because it seems not to be possible to copy a row of a queryset to an list.
Someone could give me an hint to the way to go?

Comment: `()` is not a list, `[]` is. Also, you should use `appointments2.append()`

Comment: I'd suggest that you shouldn't be doing any of this in the view.  Use Bootstrap's flexbox columns in the template, and slice the queryset there to split it between columns.